# metodo de Insercion binaria, ayuda

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

insercion binaria con dos errores.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[]kyuu)
    {
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      int[] x = {23,44,12,-19,98,102,56,36,21,33,67};
      Main hola = new Main();
      //ordena la matriz de numeros
      hola.ordenar(x);
      //imprime la matriz de numeros
      hola.imprimir(x);
      int busqueda=-19;
      hola.busquedaBinaria(x, busqueda);
    }

    public void ordenar(int[] x)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
          int menor = this.inferior(x, i);
          int temp = x[i];
          x[i] = x[menor];
          x[menor] = temp;
        }
    }

    private int inferior(int[] x, int  inf)
    {
      int menor = inf;
      for(int i = inf; i < x.length; i++)
      {
      if(x[i] < x[menor])
       {
      menor = i;
       }
      }
    }
}
```

y tambien me podrian explicar diferencias entre binaria y directa y sort... 
gracias..[image: Estos son los errores que me salen]

Answer (score 1):

No has definido los métodos `imprimir` y `busquedaBinaria` en tu clase `Main` (solo veo `ordenar` e `inferior`). Así que, obvio que el compilador no entiende estas sentencias:

```
hola.imprimir(x);
// ...
hola.busquedaBinaria(x, busqueda);
```